# Need to develop look & feel of an ASP.NET site another website

Tags: asp.net, css, stylesheet, branding, view-source

I am trying to create masterpage and necessary styles in my asp.net site.
I am trying to replicate the colors, styles from the below website.

www.power-tek.com

1. I am trying to find which is the color code in the background (the one is greyish-black)?
2. I am also trying to find out the area that has the search button and also the menu areas.

I opened the page in chrome and went to developer settings. I then tried to focus on the particular area that I am looking for but I still not able to find it.

Can anyone suggest please,

Thanks.

Comment: Firefox + Web Developer Toolbar + Rainbow = there's your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That background is an image. on the chrome browser click f12. then click on element. then click on body element. then u can see styles on the right bottom of the screen. ther u will get all the styles forthe attribute. for the button style, u can right click on the button then go inspect element. it will show u all styles applied to the button on the right bootom of the screen.

[image]

BG is an image. look the picture to finfd the image details
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am looking for the color-code of the background image in the website I mentioned above. I still can't find it using chrome developer tools.

Comment: hi i have updated my answer. u can find the background details in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The background is a repeating seamless image so you cant get a color code. You can use color picker plugins for chrome and firefox that give you a hex code for whatever color you are hover over even if its a image. Also what do you mean " I am also trying to find out the area that has the search button and also the menu areas." ? Are you trying to get those colors to or just focus it with dev tools?

Comment: Thanks for inputs. Yes I was trying to get the colors as well as the style (look/feel) around the menus. I need to have same style in my page.

Comment: The color picker I tried shows the color but it is not of the design/pattern as that of the background image in the website I mentioned. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You would have to use some type of graphics program such as GIMP to make the image then use css to make it a repeating background image.